# Facing Authentication Issue in GitHub Windows Desktop app at the time of Initial commit

Tags: authentication, github

I am able to login GitHub account on Web login. But in Windows desktop app,
I am able to publish, fork and clone repository but at the time of initial commit, it is always saying authentication issue.

I have tried all the points given in popup-box as by signing-out and signing-in again, by creating GitHub PAT (Personal access token) token also.

I have checked my account settings, In settings, the main branch is the default branch and SSH is also enabled in app and the repository type is public. Even I am able to see changes and created repositories on web login also.

Usually it'll be a credential problem, but it is not. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with php itself. Removing the tag

Comment: Anyway we don't know which of the issues listed in the screenshot is applicable to you, because we know absolutely nothing about your account or your environment (and it's not clear how you think we would). If you're unsure then you just need to work through that list one at a time until you find the cause. I don't know if GitHub offers support but if so then you could also speak to them. It's not really a problem we can solve here.